# Using CoffeeScript with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, tampermonkey

Since I prefer CoffeeScript, this is the best method I have found for using it with Tampermonkey.

See answer below.

Comment: Ironically, the OP's answer, below, only works because Tampermonkey strove to emulate a `<><![CDATA[` functionality that Greasemonkey (Firefox) has since deprecated and removed.

Comment: Interesting!  I couldn't think of a better multi-line sting method.

Comment: ECMAScript 6 has backtick support.  Works in current FF; not yet in Chrome. Meanwhile, [this answer's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6480881/331508) code shows a method that works on most (¿all *current*?) browsers.

Comment: Chrome now has support for template strings too. However, when embedding CoffeeScript using backticks, destructuring assignments are somehow pre-compiled by Tampermonkey and therefore cause the compilation to fail.

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1: Require CoffeeScript

In your `==UserScript==` definition, add:

```
// @require http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js
```

### Step 2: Define the evaluator function and write your CS

The source uses JS "inline string" then compiles it.

**Full Example:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Coffeescript test
// @include  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @require  http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js
// ==/UserScript==

function evalCS(source) {
  // Compile source to Coffeescript (Array)
  var coffeescript = CoffeeScript.compile(source.toString()).split("\n");

  // Prepend 'debugger'
  coffeescript[1] = "debugger;" + coffeescript[1];

  // Join and eval
  eval(coffeescript.join("\n"));
}

// Script Source
// -------------
evalCS(<><![CDATA[

# CoffeeScript here...
# --------------------
foo = "Foo"
alert foo

]]></>);
```

Based off of [this forum post](http://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=331)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to have my CoffeeScript in a separate file. Proper syntax highlighting, less noise and the possibility to have separate module files for bigger projects are a few advantages of that approach.

So you have your actual user script, say `main.user.js`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// …
// @grant         GM_getResourceText
// @require       http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js
// @resource      coffee main.coffee
// ==/UserScript==

eval(CoffeeScript.compile(GM_getResourceText('coffee')));
```

And beside it you have your coffee file (or files), in this case `main.coffee`.

Now you just have to install the user script by URI. I usually just create a multi-file gist for that. If you don't like to have your script sitting on some server, you can [use file URIs](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=316) too.

Answer (score 1):

Important: go to Chrome's extensions page and check if the "Allow access to file URLs" setting is enabled for Tampermonkey.

Then write your CoffeScript code in a separate file and reference it as a resource in your Tampermonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Tampermonkey CoffeeScript Test
// @namespace    http://your.namespace
// @version      0.1
// @author       your@email.com
// @match        http://*/*
// @grant        GM_getResourceText
// @require      http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js
// @resource     coffee file:///home/path/to/script.coffee
// ==/UserScript==

eval(CoffeeScript.compile(GM_getResourceText('coffee')));
```