# How to add Start and Stop buttons for a timer / stopwatch using Tampermonkey

Tags: userscripts, tampermonkey

How do I create a Tampermonkey code with start stop buttons for timer?

- When I select "start", the start time should be noted (ex: 1.30 PM).
- When I select "stop", the stop time should be noted (ex: 1.35 PM)
- And the time taken (ex: 5 min) should be displayed.

Is it possible to create this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This similar to [Add a JavaScript button using Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480082/add-a-javascript-button-using-greasemonkey-or-tampermonkey), see that question for formatting and positioning ideas.

It is recommended that you use the [`Performance` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) or the [Moment.js library](https://momentjs.com/) to handle the timing and/or time formatting.  Or see: [How to convert time milliseconds to hours, min, sec format in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700283/how-to-convert-time-milliseconds-to-hours-min-sec-format-in-javascript) to do formatting the hard way.

Here is **a complete working Tampermonkey userscript** to illustrate the basics.

You can run the code snippet or install it using Tampermonkey to see it in action.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Add a stopwatch / elapsed time button
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

var gblButtonClickTime;

$("body").prepend ( `
    <div id="tmStopWatchBlck">
        <button id="tmStopWatchBttn">Start</button>
        <span id="tmTimeStat">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
` );

$("#tmStopWatchBttn").click ( zEvent => {
    var statusNode  = $("#tmTimeStat");
    var tmrButton   = $(zEvent.target);

    //--- Button text is either "Start" or "Stop".
    if (tmrButton.text() === "Start") {
        //-- Start the timer
        tmrButton.text ("Stop");
        statusNode.css ("background", "lightyellow");

        gblButtonClickTime = performance.now ();
        console.log (
            "Timer started at: ", gblButtonClickTime.toFixed(0), new Date()
        );
    }
    else {
        //-- Stop the timer
        tmrButton.text ("Start");
        statusNode.css ("background", "lightgreen");

        var stopTime        = performance.now ();
        var elapsedtime     = stopTime - gblButtonClickTime;  // Milliseconds
        var purtyElpsdTime  = (elapsedtime / 1000).toFixed(3) + " seconds";
        console.log (
            "Timer stopped at: ", stopTime.toFixed(0), new Date(),
            "Elapsed: ", purtyElpsdTime
        );
        statusNode.text (purtyElpsdTime);
    }
} );

GM_addStyle ( `
    #tmStopWatchBttn {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: 0.5ex 1em;
        width: 5em;
    }
    #tmTimeStat {
        margin-left: 1em;
        padding: 0.2ex 2ex;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        border-radius: 0.5ex;
    }
` );

/********************************************************************
******* Everything below this block is simulated target page. *******
******* It's NOT part of the userscript.                      *******
********************************************************************/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://greasyfork.org/scripts/44560-gm-addstyle-shim/code/GM_addStyle_shim.js"></script>
```

Comment: i am able to get only the start and stop with the time taken, but not getting the start and end time like running in code snippet

Comment: @ZackTylor, This is a programming site; not a script writing service.  You see the start/stop times in the browser console (Ctrl-Shift-J).  I've shown you ***how*** to code the kind of thing you want.  It's up to you to adapt it to your exact purposes -- especially since the question was not clear on the desired output. ... This question is answered.  If you need additional help: Mark this accpted then ask a new question, giving the appropriate details and showing what you attempted to solve the programming problem.  See [ask].